# SQL: How to include non-aggregate in a aggregate Select statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this below Teradata query:

```
create volatile table Sales_Record as (select max(a2.MDL_DESC),max(a3.DMD_DESC) FROM 
MDL_DD_DESC a2, DMD_DD_DESC a3);
```

When trying to execute the query with the following:

```
create volatile table Sales_Record as (select a1.SAL_DT SAL_DT,max(a2.MDL_DESC),max(a3.DMD_DESC) FROM SAL_DD_DT a1,
MDL_DD_DESC a2, DMD_DD_DESC a3);
```

getting error:

```
Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.
```

How can I add `a1.SAL_DT SAL_DT` to the query of aggregate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`GROUP BY` clause](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/spi1472240808529.html):

```
select a1.SAL_DT SAL_DT,max(a2.MDL_DESC),max(a3.DMD_DESC) 
FROM SAL_DD_DT a1, MDL_DD_DESC a2, DMD_DD_DESC a3 
GROUP BY a1.SAL_DT
```

And are you sure this is how you want to join those tables? It seems like you're getting the product of every possible combination between them, with nothing to relate the tables to each other, which is rarely what anyone wants.